# Pontrjagin ring structure on homology of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there any good reference for the Pontrjagin ring structure on 
$$
H_\ast(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,k);\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong H_\ast(\Omega K(\mathbb{Z}/2,k+1);\mathbb{Z}/2)?
$$
I am familiar with Serre's theorem describing the mod 2 cohomology ring structure. I'm also aware that the action of the Dyer--Lashof operations on this infinite loop space is trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By naturality and the external Cartan formula, the standard polynomial generators of $H^*(K(\mathbf{Z}/2,k);\mathbf{Z}/2)$ given by iterated Steenrod operations on the fundamental class are primitive.  Therefore the homology is a divided power algebra on the dual elements.